# $this->request->getPost('email') doesn't give any value while doing axios POST request

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, axios, codeigniter-4

I'm using axios to make HTTP request POST. Here's my axios code to request

```
async onFormSubmit(input_data){    
  const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', {
    email: input_data['email'],
    password: input_data['password']
  });
```

After that in the backend I using codeigniter 4 and get the post request's value using this code

`return json_encode($this->request->getPost('email'));`

And then the data return is Null. How exactly to receive post data from axios post?

Nb:

1. I directly return the data just to look directly for the value that posted by axios
2. The value of input_data['email'] is not None (Already check that in console before do the axios post)

Comment: Does 'email' at least appears in your ajax request? You can check it in the network tab with any devtools.

Comment: yes.. Thanks for your reply. I've figured out the problem. That because i use method getPost. The correct one should be getJson

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
use getJson rather than getPost